# Is there a keyboard shortcut in Postman to get to the Body of a request?

Tags: postman

After clicking on a saved request in Postman, I get a view that looks like this:
[image: Postman]

To view the body, I need to click "Body".

This is not a big deal, except if I am doing this with 20 or so requests, looking for something particular in the body of each one, it would be a much nicer work-flow to be able to use a keyboard shortcut to reach that section.

Does anybody know of such a shortcut, or alternative way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can check out available shortcuts from the App's settings (Wrench icon on the right > Settings > Shortcuts tab).  At this point I don't think there's a way to do what you're asking.

However, as an alternative...

You could export the collection, edit the json directly in your favourite text editor and then import the collection back in.  If you have to do a global find/replace this can be a huge time saver.